# How to reclassify data around 2 lines created from arbitrary integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a plot with 2 lines (created from specific equations) and I am trying to create new pandas dataframes based on where my data falls relative to the lines.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
        import numpy as np 
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([ [-1.0, 0], [-1.0, 1.5], [-0.15, 0], [0.5, 0.5] ], columns=['x', 'y']) 
        df                                                                      
Out[2]: 
      x    y
0 -1.00  0.0
1 -1.00  1.5
2 -0.15  0.0
3  0.5  0.5
```

I have two lines which are going to be plotted with the data in df, the lines are defined as:

```
In [3]: def line1(): 
            x1 = np.linspace(-2, 0, 500) 
            y1 = 0.61/(x1 - 0.05) +1.3 
            return x1, y1 
         
        def line2(): 
            x2 = np.linspace(-2, 0.3, 500) 
            y2 = 0.61/(x2 - 0.47) + 1.19 
            return x2, y2
```

The plot looks as such:
[image]

So from df, I would like to create 4 new dataframes based on the 4 locations where the points fall (e.g. df_red, df_green, df_black, df_blue).
My current thinking is to try something like this:

```
In [4]: line_orange = line1() 
        line_magenta = line2() 
         
        df_red = df[ (df.x < line_orange) & (df.y < line_magenta) ] 
        df_green = df[ (df.x < -0.9) & (df.y > line_magenta) ] 
        df_black = df[ (df.x < line_magenta) & (df.x > line_orange) ] 
        df_blue = df[ (df.x > line_magenta) ]
```

Now I'm not 100% sure where these parameters will correctly classify my points, but I can't check because this sort of classification does not work -- it raises:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (2,500)
```

I am open to suggestions for a methodology to classify my points. I would not like to loop over my actual dataframe since it is very large. Don't worry about my actual classification, I can play around with that as soon as I find a way to split up the data, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method. Define two functions to calculate the points of both lines:

```
def f1(x):
    return 0.61/(x - 0.05) +1.3 

def f2(x):
    return 0.61/(x - 0.47) + 1.19
```

Then compare the position of `y` relative to `f1(x)` and `f2(x)` and use it to make groups:

```
groups = {group: d for group,d in df.groupby([df['y'].gt(f1(df['x'])),
                                              df['y'].gt(f2(df['x']))])}
```

output:

```
{(False,
  False):      x    y
 0 -1.0  0.0
 3  0.5  0.5,
 (True,
  False):       x    y
 2 -0.15  0.0,
 (True,
  True):      x    y
 1 -1.0  1.5}
```

if you want something as dataframe:

```
df['above_f1'] = df['y'].gt(f1(df['x']))
df['above_f2'] = df['y'].gt(f2(df['x']))
df.set_index(['above_f1', 'above_f2']).sort_index()
```

output:

```
                      x    y
above_f1 above_f2           
False    False    -1.00  0.0
         False     0.50  0.5
True     False    -0.15  0.0
         True     -1.00  1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Two lines that intersect at one point can split the page into four sections. In this method, the line's equation can be used to obtain the class of any point.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
df = pd.DataFrame([ [-1.0, 0], [-1.0, 1.5], [-0.15, 0], [0.5, 0.5] ], columns=['x', 'y'])  
line1 = lambda x,y:y>=(0.61/(x - 0.05) +1.3)
line2 = lambda x,y:y>=(0.61/(x - 0.47) + 1.19)
classifier = lambda al1, al2: (4 if al2 else 3) if al1 else (2 if al2 else 1)
df['above_line_1'] = df.apply(lambda row:line1(row.x, row.y), axis=1)
df['above_line_2'] = df.apply(lambda row:line2(row.x, row.y), axis=1)
df['class'] = df.apply(lambda row:classifier(row.above_line_1, row.above_line_2), axis=1)
```

output:

```
    x   y   above_line_1    above_line_2    class
0   -1.00   0.0     False   False   1
1   -1.00   1.5     True    True    4
2   -0.15   0.0     True    False   3
3   0.50    0.5     False   False   1
```